# Orientation Landscape iOS 5 on xCode 4.6

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, ios6, orientation

I want my app to be landscape. I tried everything, my storyboard's orientations are landscape, I changed the supported orientations and the initial orientation in info.plist. Can anyone help me?

In iOS 6 simulator it is landscape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS 5 you need to implement the following method in everyone of your view controllers.

```
// Called only in IO 5 and earlier.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft );
}
```

And set UIInterfaceOrientation "Initial interface orientation
" to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight in your Info.plist

And lay out your views in landscape mode.

Per [Apple's developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)